# How to pass coefficient derived from lm from train to test?

Tags: r

I have devided my dataset to 2 parts (Train 80% and Test 20%)

```
randomData<-  head(diamonds,n=length(diamonds$price)*0.8)
test      <-  tail(diamonds,n=length(diamonds$price)*0.2)
```

Then i tried to train a linear model with train data

```
res<-lm(price ~carat+cut+color+clarity+depth+table+x+y+z,data=randomData) #Train
```

But then **i need to apply the coefficients which come from train part to the test 
,but i have no idea how i can do it?**

it seems that i should somehow pass `res$coefficients`  to `lm` and apply the `test` as my data

Comment: using the `predict` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"train" and "test" are just machine learning jargon for "fit" and "predict". You've done the fit, now predict:

```
predict(res,newdata=test)
```